# Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 2 of substring function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, substring

I'm trying to put 2x'-' in phone number and I'm getting the following error

> Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 2 of substring
> function.

I'm working on Tsql. I also try 'mid' function - no results. I need a result like '123-456-789'.

```
declare @tel nvarchar(20) = 123456789
set @tel = (select left (@tel, '3'))+'-'+(select substring (@tel, '4','3'))+'-'+(select right (@tel, '3'))
select @tel
```

Comment: The error **literally** tells you the problem; *"data type varchar is invalid for argument 2"*. `'3'` is a `varchar` value; `int` values don't have single quotes. The first step to debugging a problem is reading the error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your Query modified as below

```
declare @tel nvarchar(20) = '123456789'
set @tel = (select left (@tel, 3))+'-'+(select substring (@tel, 4,3))+'-'+(select right (@tel, 3))
select @tel
```

can Re write as below

```
declare @tel nvarchar(20) = '123456789'
set @tel = left (@tel, 3)+'-'+substring (@tel, 4,3)+'-'+ right (@tel, 3)
select @tel
```

Comment: suitable for MSSQL

Comment: You don't explain what you change here, and why leave those `SELECT`'s in the expression? None of them are needed.

Comment: @Larnu just corrected his mistake where he went wrong. just re write query now specify if need to change any

Comment: You haven't told the OP what that mistake was though. Also, I can't see anywhere the OP states they identify as male; don't assume genders.